# bashrc does not recognize export on macos

Tags: bash, macos

I was in the process of installing *vitasdk* to my mac, when I was suddenly stopped by the fact that my `.bashrc` did not have the proper exports. `.bashrc` did not exist at first, so I needed to make one from scratch, when I created the `~/.bashrc` file and added them it did not work. At first, I thought it was because I was using `zsh`, so I switched back to `bash` and it still won't work.

Does anyone why this is happening? I have looked everywhere online and cannot find anything to solve this specific problem.

here is my code for `~/.bashrc`:

```
export VITASDK=/usr/local/vitasdk
export PATH=$VITASDK/bin:$PATH # add vitasdk tool to $PATH
```

and `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

here is the output from the terminal when I run `sudo ./bootstrap-vitasdk.sh`:

```
 Installing vitasdk to /usr/local/vitasdk

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open

    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request

    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request

    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders

    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output

    self.send(msg)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send

    self.connect()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect

    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket

    return self.sslsocket_class._create(

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create

    self.do_handshake()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake

    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>

  File "<stdin>", line 25, in fetch_last_release

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen

    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open

    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open

    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain

    result = func(*args)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open

    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open

    raise URLError(err)

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>

http://: Invalid host name.

Please add the following to the bottom of your .bashrc:

export VITASDK=/usr/local/vitasdk

export PATH=$VITASDK/bin:$PATHhere
```

Comment: @steeldriver the wget part actually seems to relate to whether or not brew is installed. For some reason the terminal doesn't recognize brew being installed so I have to install it, when I do install brew the error changes, I will add the other error to the post

Comment: I still don't think your issue is related to your bashrc or exports - that message gets printed at the end of the install process regardless of success or failure. It looks more like the issue now is that the installer script is unable to download the appropriate archive for your OS

Comment: What does it say for `echo "$VITASDK"`? If the path is returned, we need to look somewhere else.